# how to get mongodb current featureCompatibilityVersion into a variable with only version

Tags: mongodb

how to get mongodb current featureCompatibilityVersion into a variable with only version

instead of printing like this

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
{ "featureCompatibilityVersion" : { "version" : "4.0" }, "ok" : 1 }
```

Assign only version to a variable using mongo shell

```
fcv_version=$(eval "mongo <connection paramaeter> --eval '<oneliner to get fcv version>')
echo $fcv_version
4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
fcv_version=$(eval "mongo <connection paramaeter> --quiet --eval 'db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } ).featureCompatibilityVersion.version')
```

Comment: Your answer will include "Shell version and connection string" and not only version... So this is not requested answer.

Comment: @JJussi, correct I added `--quiet` option

Answer (score 2):

Put that answer to variable and then read only wanted value:

```
cont:PRIMARY> var h=db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
cont:PRIMARY> h.featureCompatibilityVersion.version
4.4
```

At your requested form:

```
[mongodb_node ~]$ m_ver=$(mongo --quiet --eval 'db.adminCommand({ getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 }).featureCompatibilityVersion.version')
[mongodb_node ~]$ echo $m_ver
4.4
```

Comment: thanks, can we get this in one line ? because I would like assign to variable when ran from mongo shell. something like - `fcv_version=$(eval "mongo <connection paramaeter> --eval '<oneliner to get fcv version>')`

Comment: That other answer didn't remember to put --quiet and that will generate extra stuff to the  answer... If you didn't notice!